# isEven recursive requires return statement?

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

I have what I think is a quick question.  Why do I require the last return statement?  Isn't the idea behind recursion that I call a function repeatedly until I get to the answer I want, and THEN I return a value?

```
// Your code here.  this does work
function isEven(num) {
  if (num == 0) return true;
  else if (num == 1) return false;
  else return isEven(num - 2);
}

// Your code here.  This does not work
function isEven(num) {
  if (num == 0) return true;
  else if (num == 1) return false;
  else isEven(num - 2);
}
```

Comment: Each call has to have a return statement to return something other than *undefined*, otherwise it returns *undefined*.

Comment: In the second version, if you called `isEven(2)`, your function would return *nothing* (well, `undefined`). Sure, it would call itself recursively, and *those* calls would return values, but they'd be thrown away.

Comment: The function which checks if a number `n` is odd or even for `O(n)` is fun :)

Answer (score 2):

In your second snippet also the recursion is happening, if you want to return the value from the recursive call to the caller then you need to return its value.

Assume you are calling `isEven(3)`, now the else part is evaluated by calling `isEvent(3-2)`, now the second call returns false, but the since the first call does not return the value returned by `isEven(1)` the initial caller will get `undefined` as its answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't the idea behind recursion that I call a function repeatedly
>   until I get to the answer I want, and THEN I return a value?

Yes you are correct. But, if you didn't use return in the first place, when your recursion starts, then you will end up return nothing, even if the child function does return something.

What you did can be demonstrate through this code:

```
function f1() {
    f2();
}

function f2() {
    return "2";
}
```

Calling f1() won't return the value of f2. Because it didn't written as that way.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it in a life example, which sounds good for me. Let me know if it is not.

Imagine the infinite line of people, marked from 1 to infinity.
Also, there is a manager with a pile of empty papers - his name is `Main`:

```
Main

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
```

They work in the following way: `Main` just gives empty papers to different people. If guy `0` gets the paper, he writes "true" on it and returns it to someone, who just gave this paper to him - whether it is `Main` or the guy in two positions to the right. Guy `1` does the same, but writes "false". All others don't know what to write, so they just pass this paper to the guy who is in two positions to the left, and when they get the answer - they **return** this paper to the original sender.

> Now, you give an empty paper to `5` - he passes this document to `3`, and he passes it to `1`. `1` writes "false" and **returns** paper to the previous owner - to `3`. `3` returns the paper with the cherished "false" to `5`. `5`, in its turn, returns it to the original sender - to the `Main`.

That's exactly what this recursion does. Calling a proper `isEven(5)` will return `false`.

If you remove `return` from the line `else return isEven(num - 2);`, then it becomes the following:

> `Main` gives an empty paper to `5` - he passes this document to `3`, and he passes it to `1`. `1` writes "false" and returns this to `3`, but the guy `3` simply does nothing with it. It nods, receives paper and throws it into a trash can. He isn't going to **return** this to guy `5`, and it's ok since guy `5` isn't expecting it. He just passed the paper to `3` and forgot it - *called the function, but didn't store or return result*. Everybody in the line simply doesn't need this paper to go back. Finally, the `Main` gets nothing. His paper has been lost somewhere on the way back.

So, calling your wrong `isEven()` with everything except for 0 or 1 will return `undefined`.

Comment: Not sure I follow any of that…